# Será que o SE está a impor algumas visões politicas com as recentes atividades no metão?

Tags: debate, comunidade

Tem havido bastante conteúdo no Stack Exchange no meu ponto de vista no minimo polemico.

Ora vejam:

["Stack Overflow Isn't Very Welcoming" especially [...] marginalized groups?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309513)

[Does Stack Exchange have an ethical responsibility to address global discrimination and marginalisation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309612)

[Moderator bans using father](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/581)

[Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1)

Muitos destes posts mostram claramente que pelas respostas que há um movimento para usar substantivos/pronomes neutros. E falam também em grupos marginalizados sem quaisquer tipo de evidencias, estudos, e dentro desses grupos nunca pertencem homem brancos (grifo meu):

> Too many people experience Stack Overflow¹ as a hostile or elitist
>   place, especially newer coders, **women, people of color, and others in
>   marginalized groups**.

Eu não estou aqui para debater politica. Eu estou aqui simplesmente para manifestar que estou **com nojo** deste tipo de discurso.

No meu ponto de vista este tipo de prática é o inicio para a censura. Eu não posso dizer mais aquilo o que quero, como quero, quando quero. Eu vou sempre ofender alguém quando escrever uma pergunta ou resposta, não importa o quanto cuidado eu tenha.

É óbvio que devo ter e **tenho** o cuidado de nunca tentar ofender ninguém e tentar ser o mais imparcial possível nas minhas publicações.

Mas quando alguém elimina uma postagem porque devia ser usado "criador do assembly" em vez de "pai do assembly" que nunca foi usado com objetivo de ofender, creio que é um pouco demais...

Qual é o objectivo de todo este zumbido que anda a acontecer?...

Comment: Bem vindo a século XXI :( O mais impressionante é que se elegem alguns grupos para serem "protegidos". Se fizerem com todos os grupos que de alguma forma sofrem discriminações sutis o mundo se torna inviável. Acho que qualquer pessoa sã não aceita discriminações que causam problemas reais para as pessoas. Também é curioso usar intolerância para combater intolerância. Falo de forma geral, não da SE que nem sabemos onde querem chegar, se vão fazer até o linite do razoável. E deixando claro que não vejo isso acontecendo (pode ser mais no SOen e nunca passou na minha frente).

Comment: @Maniero Eu nem me atrevi a postar isto no meta, eu tenho medo e  sei que vai ter 0 efeito! Eu muito honestamente nao sei qual é o objetivo deste todo fernezim. Eu gostava que as pessoas tivessem um pouco mais de abertura e percebessem que mesmo que a gente nao use "linguagem politicamente correta" a gente nao está a exclui-las nem ofende-las...

Comment: Eu gostei da sua coleção de posts relacionados a isso, já é algum efeito  (pronto não é mais zero). E também não acho que vai ser apagado pq não consigo imaginar um moderador do nosso site que faria uma coisa dessas, e se for apagado a gente desapaga :) (só to curioso de como vc foi achar aquele post no meta do retrocomputing, mas blz)

Comment: @Math O usuário postou uma [pergutna quase igual no meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309695). Eu nao quiz linkar para aí porque nao achei relevante ter dois links.

Comment: Recomendo muito ver o vídeo do Jordan Peterson vs a repórter Newman. Ele fala sobre este risco de que as pessoas deixem de falar a verdade só porque corre o risco de ofender alguém, e mostra como este tipo de discurso é preocupante usando um exemplo dentro da própria entrevista. É muito bom mesmo. Fora a aula que ele dá de como se manter calmo, analítico, atento apenas aos fatos em meio a uma discussão polêmica.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMcjxSThD54

Comment: Curioso como vão acabar criando uma situação onde ninguém mais sabe o que é certo ou errado. Isto é preocupante. Até agora só pessoas muito fora do eixo tem dificuldade em entender o que é certo ou errado, mesmo quando as vezes erram o ponto. Se vão tratar mais fortemente as pessoas mal intencionadas, ok pra mim, mas se vão abandonar a ideia de sempre considerar boa intenção ou começar baixar a barra da boa intenção pro nível que melhor convier pra eles, aí complica. Aí entramos em arbitrariedades nocivas. Eu queria entender o que está de errado hoje. Nem isso eu sei.

Comment: Infelizmente tá com cara de "politicamente correto". E não tem nada mais "politicamente incorreto" do que isso, pois sempre se trata de um grupo decidindo o que os outros podem ou não dizer. Aliás, essas idéias sempre me ofendem, pois promovem desequilíbrio através de uma classificação artificial das pessoas e dos "certos e errados". Mas eu posso ser ofendido pelas pessoas, pois não sou do "grupo certo", né?

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service/public Parece que eles sabem que vão tomar muitos processos e estão se precavendo.

Comment: @Maniero eu não tenho nada contra, mas é só ser adulto e dizer "olha gente, acreditamos em A, B, e C, somos uma empresa com tal ideologia então as NOSSAS regras sao D, E, F, e você tem que segui-las". Agora, de gente tentando me convencer que eu sou o errado e eles tão certos, achei que já tinhamos passado da fase faz uns meses. Mas parece que essa idéia tá na moda de novo, em maior escala.

Comment: @Bacco em nenhum momento eu vi a equipe da SE dizendo a alguém "você está errado e o certo é isso". O que eu vi até agora foi exatamente o que você propõe: `é só ser adulto e dizer "olha gente, acreditamos em A, B, e C, somos uma empresa com tal ideologia então as NOSSAS regras sao D, E, F, e você tem que segui-las"`. Isso é algo que o Joel vem dizendo a tempos, o Shog é um porta-voz disso, e mesmo nos posts mencionados houve extensa discussão sobre o assunto.

Comment: @Renan talvez você não tenha frequentado o chat da rede por tempo suficiente. Lá eu vi muito disso há um tempo atrás. Mas não vem ao caso estender demais essa parte. Note que usei a expressão "está com cara de", não é uma afirmação de que vá necessariamente acontecer desta forma. É uma suposição baseada em experiências passadas e tendências.

Comment: @Bacco acabei de defender um grupo de oprimidos https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6397800170699911168?commentUrn=urn%3Ali%3Acomment%3A%28activity%3A6397800170699911168%2C6397840525726085121%29 :) E é sério o que eu falei, penso assim mesmo, apesar da minha ação em isolado ter sido sarcástica :)

Comment: Por este andar um discurso do tipo *"Caros amigos, estamos todos aqui hoje reunidos com o intuito de debater os problemas que os cidadãos actualmente (...)"* terá de ser *"Caros amigos e amigas, estamos todos e todas aqui hoje reunidos e reunidas com o intuito de debater os problemas que os cidadãos e cidadãs actualmente enfrentam (...)"*. Mesmo assim haverá alguém que se indignará por as referências no feminino não virem em primeiro lugar.

Comment: @ramaral Exatamente é isso que estou a tentar transmitir. Eu acho que se está a tornar mais da seguinte forma. "Caros colegas, irrespetivo de sexo, religiao, etnia, cultura, ou naturalidade..."

Comment: Fiz um teste de denunciar algo claramente irresponsável e até apologia ao crime, o que o Facebook mandou: `Agradecemos por nos avisar sobre isso. Examinamos a foto e, embora ela não vá contra nenhum dos nossos Padrões da Comunidade específicos, você fez a coisa certa ao nos informar sobre ela. **Entendemos que pode ser ofensivo ou desagradável *para você***, por isso, queremos que você veja menos conteúdo como esse no futuro.` Ou seja, eles não combatem intolerância com intolerância, não são hipócritas. Tentei denunciar outras coisas que são consideradas erradas pela maioria, nem tem a opção.

Comment: @Maniero Se são hipócritas é outra discussão, mas basta olhar para o facebook pra ver que eles combatem muito mal a intolerância.

Comment: @bfavaretto concordo, mas não é com intolerância que vão resolver o problema da intolerância. Algumas pessoas odeiam a democracia mas a usam quando são do próprio interesse, por isso nunca dizem o quanto odeiam o que é democrático. A SE também combate muito mal até mesmo a qualidade ruim de conteúdo técnico, desagradando praticamente todo mundo exceto quem postou. Apagar é censurar. Alertar não é. Vale pra questões técnicas, vale questões socioculturais. Apagar só é válido se for crime ou impede o direito de alguém, depois do devido processo com os envolvidos.Saiu disso há hipocrisia e censura

Comment: @Maniero Vou voltar o foco aqui pro SO/SOpt porque falar de Facebook seria um parênteses muito longo. Aqui eu acho que as regras de comportamento existentes são bem eficientes. Basta comparar o conteúdo daqui com boa parte da internet. Eu não acho que sejamos intolerantes na maneira como moderamos. Também ainda não vi nenhuma "regra" ou prática nova, surgida desse debate, que eu tenha achado intolerante. Você viu algo? Como eu falei pro Gabe, nesse assunto eu acho melhor debater fatos concretos.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu também, por isso não precisa mudar nada. Estamos especulando, mas se precisa mudar porque tem gente que se sente mal com coisas ridículas, é para ser mais rígido do que é e vai produzir maluquices. Se não for nada disso, estão criando a tempestade no copo d'água. E vão dizer que nós é que estamos. Estava tudo tranquilo, sem problemas. Quantas vezes viu realmente alguém cometendo um crime, prejudicar de fato alguém aqui? Exclui algum maluco ideológico que acha que tudo **o que ele acredita** pode ser ofensivo, mas não é o que os outros acham diferente dele.

Comment: Eu espero que eles tomem mais cuidado para fazer as coisas e propor coisas concretas. Só pra variar meterem os pés pelas mãos. São essas pessoas que querem definir o que é bom ou ruim para as pessoas. E eu tenho usado o Quora, não tem nada do que tem aqui e o conteúdo geral lá é melhor que aqui, muito melhor, em todos os sentidos. (as perguntas são ruins, tem problemas lá, mas não vale debater aqui, só estou colocando que a solução pros problemas e dar o incentivo certo, tomar as atitudes certas com os reais problemas, e "escolher" quem você quer participando, abraçar todo mundo dá problema).

Comment: Eu não sou o único que acha que as empresas precisam se comunicar melhor com seus consumidores: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/993148036980277249

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Too many people experience Stack Overflow¹ as a hostile or elitist place, especially newer coders, women, people of color, and others in marginalized groups.

Na minha visão essa expressão foi totalmente infeliz, mas aí entramos em debate de ideias que envolve todo um contexto de politicamente correto que também desencadeia assuntos políticos desnecessários.

Se estamos usufruindo de uma ferramente cuja empresa por trás é de capital privado e que por sua vez distribui uma política de utilização, temos de segui-lá?

Sim, porém a própria empresa nos fornece meios de expor um dos nossos princípios básicos, o princípio da livre manifestação, ou seja, o meta foi criado a fim de conversar sobre problemas e ideias que afetam toda a rede.

Se algo lhe incomoda em relação ao modo e circunstâncias em que perguntas vem sendo excluídas, sua manifestação sobre isso no SO, SOpt, etc.. é totalmente válida.

Comment: Ás vezes é preciso algúem explicar aquilo que está mesmo á frente dos nossos olhos...

Answer (score 7):

> No meu ponto de vista este tipo de prática é o inicio para a censura.

Eu concordaria com você se a Stack Exchange fosse uma instituição pública. Porém:

- Se trata de uma empresa de capital privado;
- A empresa é de um país com uma cultura diferente da maioria dos aqui presentes;
- Em nenhum momento houve lobby ou movimentação política coordenada pela Stack Exchange para mudar a legislação sobre expressão no país em que você vive;

Se de alguma forma o Stack Overflow não lhe agrada, você tem toda a **liberdade** de criar a sua própria rede, com suas próprias normas de conduta. Mas se continuar por aqui, lembre-se de que para criar uma conta no Stack Overflow você deve concordar com o [código de conduta da SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback). Você concordou com uma EULA, então deve seguí-la.

Comment: As empresas também tem capacidade para censurar, quer seja por parte da própria empresa quer seja parte dos usuários que fazem parte da comunidade. Assim como acontece no Twitter, no Youtube e no Facebook parece que vai acontecer aqui também. Eu nao estou a dizer que é culpa da empresa é simplesmente como a comunidade anda a manifestar

Comment: Censura é censura, não importa de quem venha. A forma como é feita é que define se é ou não censura. Não censura não é permitir tudo, censura é impor um padrão moral. De fato ninguém é obrigado a usar um produto que impõe algo. Ninguém está dizendo que eles não podem querer impor o que querem (ainda que tenha alguma legislação no Brasil, onde eles atuam que dá algumas garantias quanto a isso). Mas se eles imporem algo que as pessoas não querem podem ter reações. É um direito das pessoas dizerem que não concordam com algo. O código de conduta é ótimo, o problema é a interpretação dela.

Comment: Ia comentar algo, mas o @Maniero já disse tudo. Censura é censura, o máximo que essa resposta fez foi concordar, algo na linha do "é particular, então eles censuram o que quiserem".

Comment: Eu acho que absurdo seria o contrário. Eu não sou religioso, eu tenho muita coisa contra religiões, mas eu não fico entrando em sites de igrejas e fazendo ataques *ad hominem* e sem sentido às pessoas que os frequentam. E se algum troll entra em um site de igreja e insulta seus fiéis, e por isso acaba expulso, eu dou à razão ao site religioso e não ao sujeito sem noção. Na mesma medida, o fundador e CEO da SE é homossexual. Se alguém ofende a população LGBT no SE, está ofendendo o dono da coisa toda e ele tem todo o direito de remover o conteúdo homofóbico da rede que é dele.

Comment: Eu também não entro em sites ideológicos pra dizer que eles estão errados. Eu entro em site para falar de programação para aprender sobre o assunto. Desrespeito às pessoas já está coberto e é inclusive *off-topic*, mas ficar com picuinha com cada letra errada que a pessoa possa usar e que alguém não gostou eu só concordo se aceitar a reclamação de todos que se sentirem ofendidos. E todos têm o direito de considerar o dono da empresa fascista se o fizer por motivos ideológicos e não porque de fato causa um problema. Note que não debato o que é certo ou errado, e sim a forma como tratar.

Answer (score 5):

Acho ótimo que nós estamos, finalmente, admitindo que o SO tem um problema histórico com diversidade e inclusão, e fazendo alguma coisa pra lidar com o problema. Já tinha passado da hora.

Espero que o SOpt siga o mesmo caminho.

Demorou bastante pra empresa dar todo o apoio necessário às equipes de desenvolvimento e comunidades, para que elas se dediquem à encontrar soluções pra isso.

Vai tornar nossos sites muito melhores.

Comment: eu concordo que o SE esteja certo em estar preocupado com inclusao e diversidade, pelos vistos há pelo menos problema em relacao á inclusao das muheres suportado nos questionários feitos pelo SE. Mas aquilo que quiz alertar no meu post é que está, pelo menos no caso do blog, tendo o efeito contrário.

E penso que alguns usuários levaram isto a peito e resultou em accoes extremas. Como eu disse "Eu não posso dizer mais aquilo o que quero, como quero, quando quero. Eu vou sempre ofender alguém ". 

Eu quero que ser simpático "be nice" mas nao quero ser censurado.

Comment: A discussão é delicada, acirra ânimos dos dois lados – se é que são só dois. O que eu não entendi até agora é o que o SO pretende fazer em termos práticos. Acho louvável terem colocado o assunto em pauta, mas deu a impressão de que foi feito de maneira atrapalhada. A reação que estamos vendo era mais que esperada, então acho que vocês deveriam de cara ter proposto mudanças concretas. Não que a reação fosse ser diferente, provavelmente ia ser pior. Mas pelo menos seria em cima de medidas concretas. Tenho dúvidas se o debate ideológico que está acontecendo vai levar a algum lugar.

Comment: @bfavaretto nenhuma novidade, né? :) Esse é o problema de tratar coisas ideologicamente. Nem dá pra debater algo porque não tem o que debater, fica só cada lado empurrando pro lado contrário. Quer apostar que medidas concretas serão impostas e não debatidas? E os problemas reais, não isolados, que são o foco do site vão sempre ficando pra trás. Pra mim o problema específico já tem solução, o que não tem é uma forma de facilitar a vida dos usuários que querem produzir e classificar conteúdos.

Comment: @bfavaretto Não discordo nem um pouco. Nossa reação foi um pouco "acelerada" por acontecimentos no Twitter nas semanas anteriores, e coisas de dentro da empresa também. No final das contas, considerando o silêncio da empresa por basicamente uma década, só se posicionar pública e enfáticamente já é alguma coisa. Não é nem de longe suficiente, mas é mais que fizemos. Há muita coisa indefinida ainda, mas pelo menos temos um "norte" oficial.

Comment: Os limites entre politicamente correto e censura são tênues. Concordo que a SOen é um punho de ferro e que devemos ter mais cuidado com usuários novos. Dito isso,esse movimento do "estou ofendido por você discordar de mim" que promove ideias como micro-ofensas, pronome neutros, e Twitter Feuds não representa a realidade da cultura Brasileira, Portuguesa ou Americana. Isso é uma viagem a la Safe Space (South Park) sendo imposta ditatorialmente como "respeito". Vou dar um voto de confiança para a Stack Overflow. Que as medidas concretas sejam para o bem de todos. Por favor procedam com cautela.

Answer (score 2):

É um fato que existem problemas relacionados à inclusão de minorias, mulheres, e outros grupos na nossa sociedade em geral e obviamente o StackOverflow reflete esses problemas.

Negar que existem esses problemas me parece irracional. Discutir civilizadamente os problemas e procurar uma solução é o que se espera de todos aqui.

Me preocupa bastante essa postagem por um motivo:

- Quantas pessoas desses grupos citados estão aqui participando dessa discussão?

Não tem nem uma. Coloquem-se no lugar de alguém desses grupos que quisesse debater civilizadamente o que foi levantado, vocês acham que seria agradável?

Não é questão de que você ofenderá alguém sempre que falar alguma coisa. Será que não vale a pena tentar usar a linguagem para fazer com que as pessoas desses grupos se sintam mais incluídas?

Para mim a mensagem é essa: **Vamos incluir as pessoas que estão se sentindo excluídas.** No fim, não é isso que queremos?